# Where is the State monad in Arrow?

Tags: kotlin

I expected to find an implementation of the `State` monad in one of the Arrow libraries, but I cannot. Like `IO`, does this have a Kotlin native alternative that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, Kotlin doesn't have such a built-in type. Kotlin is note pure-FP so that you can have a mutable state.